# mysql combining order by random () and order by value --possible?

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-order-by, social-networking

I want to know if it is possible to fetch random arrays from database but also privileging certain arrays based on a value of an array (order by *** sort of thing)
I'll explain myself. I have some posts to display randomly to the users in a php application but I also want to show the popular ones first.
I don't know if I was really clear, thanks for your help !

Comment: Putting `RAND()` in and `ORDER BY` statement is a fantastic way to tank the performance of the database, and if I catch anyone that works with me doing it it is cause for a public shaming.

Comment: Okay... Do you have another option that lets you sort your data in a database other than order by? I don't think so

Comment: Well the answer certainly isn't being snippy, that's for certain. http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY popular DESC, RANDOM()
```

Assuming `popular` is `1` or `0`, this will show the popular ones first, then the unpopular ones. Within each category they'll be random.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be used for selecting 5 random entries ordered by top popularity.

```
SELECT MIN(ID), MAX(ID) FROM table INTO @min, @max;
SET @range = @max - @min;
SET @mr = @min + ((@range / 1000) * (rand() * 1000));

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= @mr and id <= @mr + 1000
ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 5;
```